# adding data to a list in python

Tags: python, list, insert

I've started learning python just a few days back and am stuck with a problem.

If, `list=['tuesday','wednesday','friday','sunday']`

I'm trying to write a function so i could pass in a specific index number and a value to insert and rather than using `list.insert(0,'monday')` then `list.insert(2,'thursday')` and so on  I could directly pass the indexes eg. `ind = [0,2....]` and `values = ['monday','thursday'....]`
and get a result as
`list = ['monday', 'tuesday','wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']`

#### tried

```
list = ['tuesday','wednesday','friday','sunday']
indexes = [0,1,2,3]
values = ['monday','thursday','saturday']
for index, value in (indexes, values):
    result = list.insert(index, value)
print (result)
```

#### and many other things but failed...help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There you have the solution:

```
list = ['tuesday','wednesday','friday','sunday']
indexes = [0,3,5]
values = ['monday','thursday','saturday']

result = list
for index in range(len(indexes)):
    result.insert(indexes[index], values[index])

print (result)
```

Please take into account return is just for functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
days = ['tuesday','wednesday','friday','sunday']
indexes = [0,3,5]
values = ['monday','thursday','saturday']
for i in range(len(indexes)):
    days.insert(indexes[i], values[i])
return days
```

Comment: your code is similar to what I was trying 

and the output is 

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8769b70b69ea> in <module>
      2 indexes = [0,1,2,3]
      3 values = ['monday','thursday','saturday']
----> 4 for index, value in (indexes, values):
      5     days.insert(index, value)
      6 return days

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Did you change the variable list to days as mentioned

Comment: be it days or list name really does not matter....but after you edits to the program, it would have worked if we gave print(days) instead of return.... and if your indexing was right....with your indexing the result would be ['monday', 'thursday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'] answer by @Eugenio is perfect ....cheers buddy

Comment: Yeah I just told like that because sometimes when i do that it got conflicted with python list one